# Desperately need assistance with WordPress migration

Tags: wordpress, migration

I've posted on the WordPress section of StackExchange and on the WordPress support forums but with no success and i'm coming under pressure from my client to get their site up and running.

I've tried without success to migrate my WP site to a different server and domain name. These are the steps I have undertaken as per the instructions and guides.

1. Downloaded the root folder of my WP site from the old domain
2. Exported my database from old domain
3. Created new database at new domain
4. Imported new database at new domain
5. Altered db name,username, password, and host in wp-config
6. Placed Search Replace DB v.2.1.0 in root folder
7. Uploaded WP folder to new server

All i'm getting is a blank screen.

What i would like to do now is ask is there any way that I can perform a fresh install of WordPress at the new server and simply copy and paste the required files and import my database from the site I was looking to migrate.

I'd really appreciate any help as I've hit a stumbling block which i can't get past on my own. Thanks.

Comment: Did you try the WP Migrate DB plugin?

Comment: I'm afraid this is too broad in scope for Stack Overflow as it's a support request rather than a Q&A, but the first thing you probably want to do is activate PHP error reporting. Check out http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php for the `WP_DEBUG` setting and turn that on. In the best case scenario, that'll give you some error message to work with. Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

If it's that important, you've probably got some sort of budget? [WPTwin](http://wptwin.com/) is an alright product, but if you're looking for a ROBUST migration deal, you can purchase [Backup Buddy](http://ithemes.com/purchase/backupbuddy/) which is what I recommend.

About 3 weeks ago we had to move our large multisite (over 200 sites at the time, now at over 1,500) to a new server. We used Backup Buddy, and it worked Seamlessly!

We also use it to set up "white label" versions of our wordpress software, so basically cloning it, and moving it to a new server under a new domain name.

It's incredibly powerful and works flawlessly! We had only one issue with it ever, and that was that only once it didn't carry over Page Templates in some subdomains. OTher than that, boy I rate it 98%, it's a great plugin, although a tad pricey, but worth it!

Answer (score 0):

I too had this issue a few weeks ago, and found that the issue was solved by changing the URL before moving the files. Plugins often are the root of issue when migrating so its important these are migrated carefully (preferably turned off when you move it).

Also, the blank screen probably means you have error reporting turned off in your php.ini. Make sure this is turned on and it should show you where you're going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I use the following procedure when migrating sites from my local dev environment, to a live environment.

1 - MySQL dump local db
2 - Open sql file in text editor. Do a find and replace on dev url updating with live url; eg http://site.loc -> http://livesite.com
3 - Create new live db, upload new SQL
4 - Upload clone of dev wordpress install
5 - Update live wp-config to reflect new db name, pw etc
6 - Check permissions on files and directories
7 - Make sure .htaccess is in place
8 - Open live site

That process never fails for me.

Comment: Could you go into more detail on Point 6 please?

Comment: http://codex.wordpress.org/Hardening_WordPress and http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_File_Permissions